# Switching from PHP7.4 to PHP8.1 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "posts" on null in (Templatefile) on line 93 98 224 232

Tags: php

Trying to update a WordPress site from PHP7.4 to 8.1 and I am getting these errors

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "posts" on null in TEMPLATEFILE on line 93

```
Line 93 
    $query_txt_ref->posts = array();
Line 98
    $query_book->posts = array();
Line 224
    $query_txt_ref_others->posts = array();
Line 232
    $query_others->posts = array();
```

Was working in 7.4 but not sure how to go about changing it. Would anyone be able to give me pointers on how to change this?

Here's a few more lines for reference.

```
    add_filter('posts_where', 'where_text_refrence');
    add_filter('posts_join','join_text_refrence');
    $query_txt_ref->posts = array();
    $query_txt_ref = new WP_Query($args_daily_devotion_txt_ref);
    remove_filter('posts_where', 'where_text_refrence');
    remove_filter('posts_join', 'join_text_refrence');

    $query_book->posts = array();
    add_filter('posts_where', 'where_botb_tags');
    $query_book = new WP_Query($args_daily_devotion);
    remove_filter('posts_where', 'where_botb_tags');
```

Comment: Presumably `$query_txt_ref` is null, then. Do some debugging to find out why. And/or consider adding code to check whether it's null before attempting to use it, if it's a reasonable possibility that might occur.

Comment: Note that in 7.4 you'd have got a warning instead of an error about it, which doesn't halt the program execution entirely. Demo: https://3v4l.org/Z32M0 . PHP8 has tried to get a bit stricter about things like this, presumably to encourage people to write less flakey code and make it easier to find certain kinds of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The `->foo` syntax refers to object properties. Until PHP/8, when you tried to write a property in a variable that is `null`, PHP would automatically create an object for you:

```
$query_txt_ref = null;
$query_txt_ref->posts = array();
var_dump($query_txt_ref);
```

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["posts"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

PHP has warned about this for many years (first notice, then warning). Currently, you no longer get an object and a fatal error is thrown.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/i9mKN)

If you were relying on the object being initialised automatically, you need to be explicit now:

```
$query_txt_ref = new stdClass();
$query_txt_ref->posts = array();
```

If it was masking a bug, you need to fix it at the source. Find where `$query_txt_ref` is initialised and figure out why it's sometimes not an object. If it's something that can be expected to happen, you need to handle it:

```
if ($query_txt_ref === null) {
    // Do something
} else {
    $query_txt_ref->posts = array();
}
```

If it cannot possibly happen, the issue will be found somewhere before initialisation.

Comment: Tried to explicitly initiate. But now I'm getting 504 nginx error. 
This is out of my league. Haha

Comment: That's **504 Gateway Timeout**. It means PHP script is taking too long to finish. It might be an infinite loop.